# Creating table data with JS function call in them

Tags: javascript, html

The function `addDropMenu` creates a drop down menu from an SQL database using `"country1"` or `"country2"` as name. When calling this function like shown below, the `<td>` tags dont seem to work, and both select fields are appended onto the "Country 1" select tag.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Country Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="country1">Country</label></td>
        <td id="myDiv1"><script>addDropMenu("country1")</script></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="country2">Country</label></td>
        <td id="myDiv2"><script>addDropMenu("country2")</script></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label for="submit">Submit</label></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="larger" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My JS function. Note that the ajax query returns a json array.

```
function addDropMenu(countryNo) {
    sql = "SELECT country_name,ISO_id from Country";
    $.get("dbQuery.php",{sql:sql}, function(countryArr) {

        var myDiv1 = document.getElementById("myDiv1");
        var myDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDiv2");
        var selectList = document.createElement("select");
        selectList.id = "mySelect";
        selectList.setAttribute("class","styled-select yellow rounded");
        selectList.setAttribute("name",countryNo);
        myDiv1.appendChild(selectList);
        myDiv2.appendChild(selectList);


        for (var i = 0; i < countryArr.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = countryArr[i].ISO_id;
            option.text = countryArr[i].country_name;
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        }

    }, "json" );
}
```

Why could this be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that you contain multiple identical IDs in your markup--that is invalid HTML. Also, what does `addDropMenu()` do? You need to show what it does. Contrary to your intuition, JS runs on the client side independently from its relative position in the markup, which means that the code doesn't just "happen" where you put the script tags at. You likely have to look into using loops (that iterate through each country), which then injects a dropdown menu at the target element (identified using a unique ID)

Comment: We need to see your JavaScript. Post a [mcve] please

Comment: what are you supposed to get as output?

Comment: Will post that and an update version of my HTML code, with different id tags.

Comment: Post has been updated.

Comment: Anything you see that might help?